# How to withdraw funds from Gnosis Safe multi-sig wallet?

Tags: gnosis, safe

I have gnosis safe wallet with funds, and It have 3 owners and sign threshold is also 3.
One of wallet owners lost his seed phrase forever.
Is there any way to recover funds from the wallet, or access to wallet lost with this seed phrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is most likely: No.

Did you enable a module that would allow you to withdraw funds without meeting the threshold?

Did they only lose the seed phrase or also any access to a copy of the generated secret key? Did they import it into MetaMask or a mobile client?

If they still have access to the derived secret key, they could import and use it to sign a transaction.

What do you mean by: `access to wallet lost with this seed phrase`?

Comment: I mean access to gnosis contract funds lost. Thank you, you answered the question.